# Git log with diff for a certain file

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

How can one get log listing combined with the differences in each commit
ie:

```
commit1  
Author
Date  
Commit message
changes between commit1 and commit2

commit2  
Author
Date
Commit message
changes between commit2 and commit3
...
```

---

Using
`git log /some/file`
Gives a listing of the commits that changed some/file

ie:

```
commit1  
Author
Date  
Commit message

commit2  
Author
Date
Commit message
...
```

However, the changes in each commit doesn't get displayed

Using
`git diff hash1..hash2 /some/file`
Gives the changes in /some/file between those two commits.
But only between those 2 commits, not through all the commits that changed /some/file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log you can use

```
git log -p path
```

to show commits that touch the specified paths, and diffs about the same specified paths.